# Are the eigenvectors of a normal matrix are orthogonal regardless of the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

*I know the sentence that for normal matrices, the eigenvectors, of different eigenvalues, are orthogonal.

Yet, I also know that every normal matrix is unitary diagonalaizable.

Also, the columns of the diagonalazing matrix is built from the eigenvectors and for a unitary matrix, the coulmns are orthogonal.

Therefore, it seems to me that all the eigenvectors of a normal matrix, and it doesnt matter if its from the same or different eigenvalue, should be orthogonal to each other.

Yet, i only familiar with the orthogonality of eigenvectors in normal matrix for distinct eigenvalues.

But, according to the explanation i gave, why not all the eigenvectors of a normal matrix are orthogonal to each other, regardeless of the eigenvalue?

Comment: Try taking the identity matrix $I$. It is normal, but every vector is an eigenvector.

Comment: The caveat here is that the column of the unitary matrix is just **one** of the possible orthogonal bases. If you take vectors belonging to different bases, then they can be not orthogonal. (unless they are referred to different eigenvalues, in which case, they are surely orthogonal)

Comment: @Exodd What about the case when the eigenvectors are linear independent but of the same eigenvalue? Your example of Identity matrix is a counter example but why my explanation in this case doesnt hold?

Comment: you think that all the eigenvactors are columns of the unitary matrix. That is wrong in general. If $v,w$ are linearly independent eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue, then they are not necessarily orthogonal, since they may not appear inside the same unitary matrix.

Comment: If any eigenvalue has multiplicity greater than one, then you can find all sorts of eigenvectors for it that are linearly independent, but not orthogonal.

Comment: If $A$ is normal then there $\rm{ exist}$ a unitary matrix $P$ with $P^*AP$ is diagonal, so here the eigenvectors are orthogonal to each other, wherever the eigenvalues are.